# How does a hive query runs in back end?

Tags: hive, execution

we know that when a hive query runs it generates map reduce jobs. can someone please explain in detail that what actually happens at back end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587873/2700344

Comment: @leftjoin I wanted to ask about how it processes in HDFS. memory-wise

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are asking about. Try to improve your question please