# Main purpose of the MetaStore in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I am a little confused on the purpose of the MetaStore. When you create a table in hive:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> (column1 data_type, column2 data_type);
LOAD DATA INPATH <HDFS_file_location> INTO table managed_table;
```

So I know this command takes the contents of the file in HDFS and creates a MetaData form of it and stores it in the MetaStore (including column types, column names, the place where it is in HDFS, etc. of each row in the HDFS file). It doesn't actually move the data from HDFS into Hive.

But what is the purpose of storing this MetaData?

When I connect to Hive using Spark SQL for example the MetaStore doesn't contain the actual information in HDFS but just MetaData. So is the MetaStore simply used by Hive to do parsing and compiling steps against the HiveQL query and to create the MapReduce jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metastore is for storing schema(table definitions including location in HDFS, serde, columns, comments, types, partition definitions, views, access permissions, etc) and statistics. There is no such operation as moving data from HDFS to Hive because Hive tables data is stored in HDFS(or other compatible filesystem like S3). You can define new table or even few tables on top of some location in HDFS and put files in it. You can change existing table location or partition location, all this information is stored in the metastore, so Hive knows how to access data.  Table is a logical object defined in the metastore and data itself are just files in some location in HDFS.

See also this answer about Hive query execution flow(high level): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587873/2700344

Comment: But when you create an internal table isn't the data from the file in HDFS moved into the Hive Warehouse directory: /user/warehouse/hive?

Comment: @ToothyRel When you delete your manged table, the data will be deleted as well. That is all the difference between External and Managed tables. When you delete External table the data will remain. So, create Managed tables when you do not want to bother deleting it's data after you do not need the table any more. Also there are Temporary tables, they will be deleted automatically after the session ends. Managed table also can be created on top of any location in HDFS.

Comment: So if I do create a Managed Table and link a file with that specific managed table, the only thing in the Hive MetaStore will be metaData about the table (like location in HDFS, serde, columns, comments, types, partition definitions, views, access permissions, etc). But the Data from the HDFS location will not be moved into the Hive Warehouse under  `/user/warehouse/hive`?

Comment: @ToothyRel  Right, Data will be not moved, managed or not managed does not matter. `/user/warehouse/hive/table_name` it can be a default location where data will be stored if you insert it using SQL and if you didn't define another location in table/partition DDL. In HDFS table or partition data is a folder in which files are stored.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense. So nothing is moved out of the actual HDFS location. But what's the point of the `/user/warehouse/hive` directory? If I create a managed table `Employee` and say `LOAD DATA INPATH /some/path/in/hdfs INTO TABLE Employee` then that data will be **COPIED** to the `user/warehouse/hive/Employee` directory. But the actual data from the `/some/path/in/hdfs` is still there in HDFS, so why even **copy** it to `user/warehouse/hive/Employee` directory?

Comment: It's `LOAD` command moves data into tables directory because data should be in tables directory to be accessible from Hive SQL. You also can move files using `cp` command. Every partition can have it's own folder. Plainly speaking, Hive table is a folder + table metadata.

Comment: Ohh ok so for managed or not managed the data from the file location in HDFS has to be moved into the location you specify in order for Hive SQL to work and access it.

Comment: Table data should be in it's folder.  You can mount table on top of some folder without moving data or you can put data into tables folde using load or cp/distcp or mv commands or SQL insert, etc. Table/partition is a folder physically. and data should be in it's folder to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Hive performs schema-on-read operations, which means that for the data to be processed in some structured manner (i.e. a table-like object), the layout of said data needs to be summarized in a relational structure

> takes the contents of the file in HDFS and creates a MetaData form of it

As far as I know, no files are actually read when you create a table.

SparkSQL connects to the metastore directly. Both Spark and HiveServer have their own query parsers. It's not part of the metastore. MapReduce/Tez/Spark jobs are also not handled by the metastore. It's just a relational database. If it's Mysql, Postgres, or Oracle, you can easily go connect to it and inspect the contents. By default, both Hive and Spark use an embedded Derby database